# rails: avoid string escaping in route parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, routes, ruby-on-rails-2

i have a route defined like this

```
map.search_by_key '/search/:search_key', :controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'my_action'
```

the param `:search_key` is used such that the urls are like this:

```
mysite.com/search/c_vehicles/c_cars/mk_suzuki
```

where search_key would be "c_vehicles/c_cars/mk_suzuki" ..

problem is .. when creating this url with the named route
`search_by_key_path("c_vehicles/c_cars/mk_suzuki")` it escapes the string ..  and creates something like:

```
mysite.com/search/c_vehicles%2Fc_cars%2Fmk_suzuki
```

this works fine but looks ugly in the address bar ..  how do i avoid this ..

I'm using rails 2.2.2 with ruby 1.8.6 (ancient i know .. in process to upgrade) ..

ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [globbed route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#route-globbing) for this and a bit of string wrangling in your controller:

> Route globbing is a way to specify that a particular parameter should be matched to all the remaining parts of a route. For example
>
> ```
> map.connect 'photo/*other', :controller => 'photos', :action => 'unknown'
> ```
>
> This route would match `photo/12` or `/photo/long/path/to/12` equally well, creating an array of path segments as the value of `params[:other]`.

Your route should look like this:

```
map.search_by_key '/search/*search_key', :controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'my_action'
#--------------------------^ Change the colon to an asterisk
```

And then in your controller:

```
def my_action
    search_for = params[:search_key].join('/')
    # ...
end
```

The same [globbing technique](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing) applies equally well in Rails-3 so upgrading this part of your application should be a simple matter switching to the new `routes.rb` methods.

This works with 2.3.8, I'm not sure about 2.2.2 though.